# Error In Starting android ap in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos S6102

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am trying to Instal my apk file in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos S6102 it installed Successfully but when i start the application it shows error

```
MyApp.apk Unexpected Closed
```

But my apk file working good on emulator i dont know why it shows this error 
please help me

This is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.misscall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.misscall.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please check the log to figure out the reason, attach the device to ur system and then check the error

Comment: I cheked the log but there is no error in my log file

Comment: is your device android api >api 10? ie > gingerbread??

Comment: download android app logcat from playstore and check the error when opening your application and post to stack!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser this application will instal on my android phone?

Comment: @MaulikSheth yeah it has gingerbread

Comment: yes you can install check it what error occured after your application closes and open logcat app it's shows error!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser thanks i will try and then i wil put error here

Comment: it could be possible that u have used methods that are nt available in gingerbread. the warning may not be shown that the method is not available since the target is 18 that supports the method. @YousufUmar